# how can copy contents of a folder which is does not have a folder name using CMD

Tags: command-line, file-transfer, xcopy

Due to virus when I open a pen drive it shows like this:

[image]

I want to make a .bat file to copy contents of this folder to another directory. I can use open cmd and using`xcopy D:\" " /s D:\` to do that function. but the problem is I can't use that code in .bat file. It does not work. help me.

Comment: A virus...  Reformat the machine.  Restore files from a back up

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking at a folder under the D: drive, which would not be a separate usb drive. You can right click and rename the folder so that you can then use that filename in your bat script.

For your virus issues i would recommend using Malwarebytes or Kaspersky Virus Removal tool to take care of those for you.

Comment: Yes, this is a local drive. This use as a example. What I need is make a batch file [ .bat] file to do this function, not manually but using a .bat file